# how create trigger query and using trigger on php

Tags: mysql, triggers

i have 2 table, table items and table borrowing.

structure items table : 
| id | items_name | stock (amount)|

structure borrowing table :
| id | items_id | date | amount |

when someone want to borrow the items, column stock will decrease (minus) as much as loan amount.

so my code is be like :

```
$items_id = $_POST['items_id'];
$datenow = date('Y-m-d');
$amount = $_POST['amount'];

$input = mysql_query("INSERT INTO borrowing VALUES('$items_id', '$datenow', '$amount')") or die(mysql_error());

$item = mysql_query("SELECT stock FROM items WHERE id='$items_id'");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($item);
$stockleft = $row['stock'] - $amount;

$update = mysql_query("UPDATE items SET siswa_nis='$stockleft'") or die(mysql_error());
```

i am worried if using that, will error on middle run.
what i want is if last query or second query error, first query will rollback, something like that.

so how the trigger and how i call trigger on php ?

thank you in advance.